# Доменное имя или IP-адрес

Tags: c#

Как можно получить доменное имя или IP-адрес текущего URL на C#?

Comment: Что значит "текущий URL"?

Comment: @Raider  например это `http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623043/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-ip-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81`  или `http://ru.stackoverflow.com/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `Uri.Host`: http://ideone.com/ulHm67

```
var uri = new Uri("http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623043/");
Console.WriteLine(uri.Host); // ru.stackoverflow.com
```

Получение IP-адреса также не проблема:

```
IPHostEntry ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(uri.DnsSafeHost);
Console.WriteLine(ip);
foreach (var addr in ip.AddressList)
    Console.WriteLine(addr);
```

На моей машине выдаёт:

```
ru.stackoverflow.com
151.101.193.69
151.101.65.69
151.101.1.69
151.101.129.69
```